Can someone lead me to an appropriate diode for what should be a simple circuit?
I'm trying to put together a simple memory saver for use in cars. I know the idea is viable because I've seen versions of it. The basic automotive system consists of a 12 V battery and generally a total load of no more than 50mA. The idea is to attach a 9 V battery (yes, the little rectangular one) in parallel with the system so that the 12 V battery can be disconnected without any of the computers powering down while the 12 V battery is replaced or charged, etc.
Concern one is the car battery overloading the 9 V battery before it's disconnected, thus the need for a diode. I've figured that the forward voltage should be about 5-5.5 V (the rough “dead” voltage of a 9 V). The reverse breakdown voltage should probably be about 20-30 volts (roughly double the battery voltage, which could be 13-14 with a strong surface charge). I would allow for a forward current of 100-200 mA, just in case.
My problem is that I've been through 6 or 8 supplier sites trying to filter by these specs, and either the parameters weren't filterable or the results were obsolete or discontinued. To add one more layer of complexity, I'd like to an include an LED, either as the functional diode or probably in parallel between the 9 V and the other diode as a confirmation, that the 9 V is not too discharged to provide the necessary current, meaning the LED would also need a forward voltage of 5-6 V and draw as little current as possible.
If someone could point me to a diode or LED/diode combination that would make this work, I would be immensely appreciative.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Can you explain how you got to the 5-5.5V forward voltage requirement? Now only are you unlikely to find a (small) diode with a spec like that, using one would result in less than 4V available from your 9V battery to power the car electronics.

@brhans - Sheer ignorance. In the words of many before me, I know just enough about this to be dangerous. Based on dozens of data sheets, a 9V is considered discharged at 4.8-5.2 volts, depending on the battery (much like a car battery is considered discharged at 11.6-12V). I was hoping that, with an LED in the circuit, I'd have a visual reference as to the 9V battery's state of charge by requiring a certain voltage to turn the diode on.

put 3 red LEDs in series to get forward voltage of about 5v. for your main question, just about any common little black diode will work fine.

An ordinary alkaline 9V battery is not capable of much current, so any common 1A diode like a 1N4004 or 1N5819 is adequate. A simple LED won't tell you how far the voltage has dropped, but a multimeter will.
If you get the diode backwards or shorted, there's a decent chance the 9V battery could explode or emit a nasty spray of caustic electrolyte, causing injury to eyes, fingers etc.
Also, anything that drains major current such as momentarily opening a door or trunk causing the dome light, trunk light or accent lights to come on will probably drag down the battery far enough to make it useless.
For both those reasons, it's preferably to use another vehicle's 12V lead-acid battery. You don't need the diode in that case.

The diode and 9V would be permanently wired to a universal connector that could be plugged into any vehicle with no threat of reverse current. The reason not to use another automotive battery is to avoid acts of oh shit, such as the positive cable falling into a ground source; it's better to let the 9V explode than to short the entire system with upwards of 1000 amps available. We (mechanics) know that there must be no change of state (i.e. opening doors or activating anything) while the 9V is at work.
